# Accessing Symfony2 global parameter in entity class

Tags: symfony, parameters, model

I have a value stored in my parameters.ini file, and I need to access it during the prepersist method of my model.

Normally I use `$this->container->getParameter('value');`, but the container is not available in the entity.

Is there a way to get parameters within an entity class?

P.S. The value is an API key for a service I am pulling info from during prepersist. Best practice is to keep keys/passwords in parameters.ini

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best practice is to use a service to persist your entity. This one would inject the *container* and set your parameter when you call your *`updateMyEntity()`* service method.

Inside your controller (or whatever you want):

```
$user = new User('foo');
$user->setSomeProperty('bar');
$userService->update($user);
```

Inside the `UserService`:

```
public function update(User $user) {
    $user->setSomeParameter($this->container->getParameter('value'));
    $this->em->persist($user);
}
```

Comment: setting up a user service is a bit more involved than I would like to get this basic function (grabbing the global param)

Comment: S2 does not expose parameters to the global space.  If you really feel you need to then access $kernel and pull it from there.  But you really should use a service.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Florent's answer, Entities are meant to be purely data objects.  They should not know about any other variables or services within your application.  I'm more curious about *why* your entity needs to know anything about an API key that is system-wide.  With very little background information, I'd say you should rethink what you are trying to do.

You need a service to interact with the API, ideally configured through the container.  I don't see what that has to do with an entity.

Comment: I am pulling the lat/long of the lphysical location entered during prepersist.

Comment: You can still do that with a service.  Here's a bundle which does exactly that: https://github.com/dustin10/VichGeographicalBundle - Using events, it checks for entities which need coordinates added, and it queries, and updates them when being saved.  Hope this helps.