# Accessing behavior in entity class Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

As the title states, I want to access a behavior in an entity. Since I can't find anything in the cookbook I'm assuming that is not the way how things should be done. Furthermore, I found this question which relates to Symphony but seems like this is also the case for Cakephp: [Accessing Symfony2 global parameter in entity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634415/accessing-symfony2-global-parameter-in-entity-class).

What I want to accomplish is that if a specific field/column (in my case named 'link') is called, automatically, always convert this field with use of an external library (in my case, creating a presigned url for a file that is stored on Amazon S3).

```
class Picture extends Entity{
    ......

    protected function _getLink($link){
       return $this->s3->getPresignedUrl($link);
    }
    ......
}
```

My question therefore is how I suppose to handle this. Should I use a afterFind method in the model which checks whether that field is accessed and thereby respond to calling the behavior? Can anyone confirm that the Symphony example also is the case for Cakephp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since I can't find anything in the cookbook I'm assuming that is not the way how things should be done.

Correct. An entity doesn't need to know *anything* about behaviors.

I don't know from where your S3 link generating code comes from, but it should be neutral to any layer and not coupled to the model layer. If that's not the case refactor it. And then use an instance of the S3 link generator in your entities accessor method, just like you show in your code example.

If you can't do that for some reason go for the afterFind() callback just as you suggested.

Symfony works different by the way, as far as I know almost everything is a service there and through how it implements DI it is in theory possible to access everything from everywhere. Guess it is easy to build spaghetti code with it if you don't know what you're doing. CakePHP prefers locators.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered but for future reference, I think you should check out [traits](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-re-usable-code-with-traits).

I usually use traits for this specific purpose or just take advantage of composer.

Comment: Ahh great! I think this also is a great solution to solve similar future problems.